# Anchor top content to BottomSheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a FrameLayout (teaserContainer) and BottomSheet (invitesContainer). The FrameLayout is outside (and above) the BottomSheet. I want the FrameLayout shrink and follow the BottomSheet, so the FremeLayout collapses as the BottomSheet expands.

What happens now is that the FrameLayout occupies the whole page because of its `android:layout_height="match_parent"` but if I set it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` it shows behind the BottomSheet and vertically centred like a FAB would.

I want that when the BottomSheet (invitesContainer) is fully expanded the FrameLayout (teaserContainer) should occupy the rest of the screen up to the toolbar.

All examples of anchoring views to the BottomSheet involve a FAB, so not any help to me here.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".social.friends.FriendsListFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/teaserContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/invitesContainer"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top">

        <com.myapp.android.common.social.friends.views.FriendsTeaser
            android:id="@+id/teaser"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            app:friendsTeaserState="EMPTY" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitesContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:alpha="0.1"
            android:background="@color/body" />

        <com.myapp.android.common.social.friends.views.FriendsConnectItem
            android:id="@+id/connectFacebook"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:friendsConnectType="facebook" />

        <com.myapp.android.common.social.friends.views.FriendsConnectItem
            android:id="@+id/connectContacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:friendsConnectType="contacts" />

        <com.myapp.android.common.social.friends.views.FriendsConnectItem
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:friendsConnectType="invite" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Solution:**
*This is a Kotlin version of Vadim's suggestion*

```
BottomSheetBehavior.from(invitesContainer).setBottomSheetCallback(object :
    BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
    }

    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
        val currentHeight = teaserContainer.height - bottomSheet.height
        val bottomSheetShiftDown = currentHeight - bottomSheet.top
        teaserContainer.setPadding(
            0,
            0,
            0,
            (bottomSheet.height + bottomSheetShiftDown)
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: You want behavior as google maps? when you pull the bottom sheet your main teaserContainer will change the height?

Comment: Yes, that's the thought..

Comment: tell me if you need my example of code onSlide method of bottom sheet.

Comment: I'll definitely appreciate any help, yes :-)

Comment: you can look my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My example is like:

```
public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        int currentHeight = teaserContainer.getHeight() - bottomSheet.getHeight();
        int bottomSheetShiftDown = currentHeight - bottomSheet.getTop();
        rootContainer.setPadding(
                0,
                0,
                0,
                (mBottomSheet.getPeekHeight() + bottomSheetShiftDown));
            }
```

and the `mBottomSheet - BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheet = BottomSheetBehavior.from(invitesContainer);`

So this will add/remove padding of yours teaserContainer when you pull it down.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. Works great! Updated my post with the complete `BottonSheetCallback` solution in Kotlin.

Comment: Thank you so much Vadim. This was of great help to me. :)